# Why is the color paler after saving a resized bitmap?

Tags: .net, vb.net, image-processing, bitmap

I am using VB.NET, loading a jpg file into a bitmap.
Then I clone the bitmap to another bitmap and save it.
No problem. The size of both files and the colors of the image are the same.
I use this code:

```
Dim mvrBitmapSrc As Bitmap = New Bitmap("D:\test.jpg", False)

Dim mvrBitmapTrg As Bitmap = DirectCast(mvrBitmapSrc.Clone(), Bitmap)
```

Then I clone and resize the bitmap to another bitmap, using:

```
Dim mvrBitmapSrc As Bitmap = New Bitmap("D:\test.jpg", False)

Dim mvrBitmapTrg As Bitmap = _
        DirectCast( _
            mvrBitmapSrc.Clone( _
                New Rectangle(0,0,CInt(mvrBitmapSrc.Width / 2),Int(mvrBitmapSrc.Height / 2)), _
                PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb _
            ), _
            Bitmap _
        )
```

When I show mvrBitmapSrc in a picturebox and do the same with 
mvrBitmapTrg, the colors on the screen are exactly the same, as they should be.

But then the problem occurs. When I save the scaled target bitmap and compare the file with the original source file, the colors are very different. The target is much darker and paler.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing.  When creating a thumbnail, I would draw the original to a new bitmap using the new desired size.  Using Clone and Rectangle like that should result in just the top left quarter of the original.

Comment: That is right. It was an example which shows the problem. Want I want to do is rescale a large amount of images using vb dotnet. The problem is that the color of the resized images is not correct.

Comment: When you copy a bitmap to another bitmap, and save the other bitmap, then the color is not good anymore. However, when you use the clone command to copy an image, and then save the image, the color is good. But when you clone an image, resize the clone and then save the clone, the color is bad again. Is there a way to keep the colors ok after resizing? Oh, and one more strange thing: When you show the cloned and resized image in a picturebox, then the colors are good. The color-problem occurs in the saved jpg-file.